# ScrollView not working in Android Programming

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I was trying to learn Android Programming. But am stuck in the ScrollView Chapter. When I run my code the Scroll function is not working.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button10" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button11" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the code as soon as it loads I see the Scroll but it immediately vanishes.

Can someone please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by it vanishes ?

Comment: When you touch the scroll area, scroll will be displayed and when you leave the scroll area the scroll will vanish.

Comment: Its a default behavior of the scrollview of android. What do you actually want?

Comment: Don't give fixed height of ScrollView. Just change it with wrap_content or match_parent.

Comment: You mean to say the scrolling indicator gets invisible when you left touch of scrollbar ? @Rahul

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you have set the height of Scroll view, just remove this and set it as a `wrap_content` and try.

So basically replace this line.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="225dp" >
```

with

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing your xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
  >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button10" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button11" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the property `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` which will make the indicator always visible even if you do not touches it.

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fadeScrollbars="false">
```

I think this is what you want.